# multiprocessing exits before doing any job

Tags: python, python-3.x, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, threadpool

I have inherited a certain parser that is supposed to parse 10 files with ~4m lines each.

The code was written in Python 2, which I updated.

There is a multiprocessing logic which i just don't seem to be able to get to work.

```
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool
import glob

DATADIR = 'home/my_dir/where/all/my/files/are'

def process_file(filepath):
    # read line by line, parse and insert to postgres database. 

def process_directory(dirpath):
    pattern = f'{dirpath}/*dat'  # files have .dat extension. 
    tp = ThreadPool(10)
    for filepath in glob.glob(pattern):
        print(filepath)
        tp.apply_async(process_file, filepath)
    tp.close()
    tp.join()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    process_directory(DATADIR)
```

I have gone through a lot of the documentation and some similar questions but it just doesn't seem to work.

With the parser code what happens is that I do get printed on the console all the paths of the file that I need parsed, but then that's it the program doesn't do anything else.

Comment: In your little snippet, when do you "run" thread?? I cant see that line, only declare Pool , close and join

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in the way you're calling `apply_async`. I made a simple reproducer of your problem, but with a slight tweak to get the result from each call:

```
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool

def func(f):
    print("hey " + f)
    return f + "1"

l = ["name", "name2", "name3"]
pool = ThreadPool(3)
out = []
for a in l:
    print(a)
    out.append(pool.apply_async(func, a))

# Check the response from each `apply_async` call
for a in out:
    a.get()

pool.close()
pool.join()
```

This returns an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "a.py", line 16, in <module>
    a.get()
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 599, in get
    raise self._value
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 119, in worker
    result = (True, func(*args, **kwds))
TypeError: func() takes 1 positional argument but 4 were given
```

It thinks you're passing four positional arguments, instead of one. This is because `apply_async` wants all the arguments passed in a tuple, like this:

```
pool.apply_async(func, (a,))
```

If you put `filepath` in a tuple when you call `apply_async`, I think you'll get the behavior you expect.

It's also worth noting that your usecase is well-suited to using `pool.map` instead of `apply_async`, which is a little more succinct:

```
pool.map(process_file, glob.glob(pattern))
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I always think how I could have gotten to this answer after knowing the answer from a senior developer. For this case I see that if I had gone to the source code (which I hadn't) I would have noticed that the function is defined like this  `def apply_async(self, func, args=(), kwds={}, callback=None, error_callback=None): ...`  - which, as you were rightly saying, takes an iterable as `args`. Thanks!

Comment: @TytireRecubans Yep, that would have worked. The [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#using-a-pool-of-workers)  also has examples of `apply_async` being used, which would have revealed the correct way to call it.